# What is an alternative to the book "Probability and Statistics" and covers the same material?

Tags: references, mathematical-statistics

Can someone recommend a textbook(s) that covers the same topics as [Probability and Statistics](http://www.whfreeman.com/Catalog/product/probabilityandstatistics-secondedition-evans/tableofcontents) by by Michael J. Evans and Jeffrey S. Rosenthal?

I find this particular textbook to be very poorly written and terse.

Comment: It would be more diplomatic--and more correct--to say that you would prefer a text with more or lengthier explanations.  If you insist on staying with the "poorly written," it would be good to provide objective support for this assertion, lest the question be closed as confrontational and contentious.

Comment: Dearm whuber, I'd be delighted to scan and email you a few pages from this wonderful book, so we can BOTH have a laugh!

Comment: I appreciate the offer.  However, a better place to vent your frustration would be on a point-of-sale site like Amazon.com, where your *thoughtful,* well-considered review could have a big impact.  (There are currently only three reviews of the book there and two are useless.)  Here, on SE, you don't need to cast aspersions on something in order to ask about alternatives :-).  You'll get good responses anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your level, Hogg Tanis and Rao (intermediate), Casella and Berger (advanced), are what I used in grad school. I liked them both.

[http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Inference-George-Casella/dp/0534243126](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126)

Amazon has it for way too much, use bookfinder to find it much much cheaper.

Not sure what your goal is, but this text is fabulous as well, but is probably more applied in nature than what you are looking at.

[http://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Econometrics-Approach-Jeffrey-Wooldridge/dp/1111531048/ref=dp_ob_title_bk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1111531048)

Comment: I'm taking a course in theoretical stats, looks like I'll be fully covered between the first two books. THanks!